# Parsing COPY's binary format to access a tsrange

Tags: postgresql, dump, date-format, copy, fields

How is tsrange stored in binary?

For example create table

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (t tsrange);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('[2010-01-01 14:30, 2010-01-01 15:30)');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('[2011-01-01 14:31, 2015-11-01 15:30)');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('[2017-01-01 14:31, 2018-11-01 15:30)');
COPY test TO '/tmp/pgcopy' WITH (FORMAT binary);
COPY test TO '/tmp/pgcopy.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

It outputs:

```
 cat /tmp/pgcopy.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                  
"[""2010-01-01 14:30:00"",""2010-01-01 15:30:00"")"
"[""2011-01-01 14:31:00"",""2015-11-01 15:30:00"")"
"[""2017-01-01 14:31:00"",""2018-11-01 15:30:00"")"


hexdump -C /tmp/pgcopy
00000000  50 47 43 4f 50 59 0a ff  0d 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PGCOPY..........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  19 02 00 00 00 08 00 01  |................|
00000020  1f 19 f9 a9 aa 00 00 00  00 08 00 01 1f 1a d0 3d  |...............=|
00000030  4e 00 00 01 00 00 00 19  02 00 00 00 08 00 01 3b  |N..............;|
00000040  c8 89 51 11 00 00 00 00  08 00 01 c6 7b 1a 3a 0e  |..Q.........{.:.|
00000050  00 00 01 00 00 00 19 02  00 00 00 08 00 01 e8 08  |................|
00000060  0d 77 11 00 00 00 00 08  00 02 1c 9a dc 4d 0e 00  |.w...........M..|
00000070  ff ff                                             |..|
00000072
```

One field is:

```
00 00 00 19 02 00 00 00 08 00 01 e8 08 0d 77 11 00 00 00 00 08  00 02 1c 9a dc 4d 0e 00
```

There:

`00000019` - is 25 bytes length

`02` - brackets

`00000008` - subfield length

`0001e808 0d771100` and `00021c9a dc4d0e00` - stored timestamp with miroseconds.

How to convert it to integer timestamp?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a minor note, `COPY .. (WITH BINARY)` doesn't have brackets. It's the flags (which represent amongst other things the brackets).

## `COPY ... (WITH BINARY)`

From [the docs on `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

> To determine the appropriate binary format for the actual tuple data you should consult the PostgreSQL source, in particular the `*send` and `*recv` functions for each column's data type (typically these functions are found in the `src/backend/utils/adt/` directory of the source distribution).

Further the docs say binary format (currently) has

- 11 bytes signature
- 4 bytes for flags
- 4 byte potential **variable-width field**, currently not in use so we skip the size (4 byte `\0\0\0\0`) this technically not nice. If these four bytes had 15, we'd have to skip over not just the four, but an addition 15.

Then the tuple has

- 2 bytes for field count

Then the fields have

- 4 byte length qualifier followed by that many bytes of field data. (Which we already in the case of `timestamp`or `tsrange`)

So essentially we skip 25 bytes to get to the first column

## The `tsrange`

So it's in the format specified by [`range_send`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/31079a4a8e66e56e48bad94d380fa6224e9ffa0d/src/backend/utils/adt/rangetypes.c#L245) You can see that explained a bit below in the comments above [`range_recv`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/31079a4a8e66e56e48bad94d380fa6224e9ffa0d/src/backend/utils/adt/rangetypes.c#L162)

> Binary representation: **The first byte is the flags**, then the lower bound (if present), then the upper bound (if present).  **Each bound is represented by a 4-byte length header and the binary representation of that bound** (as returned by a call to the send function for the subtype).

## The `timestamp` subtype

In your case, that subtype is timestamp and the send is  [`timestamp_send`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/31079a4a8e66e56e48bad94d380fa6224e9ffa0d/src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c#L273).

You can see a timestamp is [stored as 8 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), and that's just sent with a simple `pq_sendint64` (a 64 bit/8 byte int). You'll have to read how [`timestamp_recv`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/31079a4a8e66e56e48bad94d380fa6224e9ffa0d/src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c#L240) works to see how you should handle a binary representation of a timestamp. Hint: it gets into a struct for in-memory representation in [`timestamp2tm`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/0e1539ba0d0a43de06c6e0572a565e73b9472538/src/interfaces/ecpg/pgtypeslib/timestamp.c#L99)

```
/* timestamp2tm()
 * Convert timestamp data type to POSIX time structure.
 * Note that year is _not_ 1900-based, but is an explicit full value.
 * Also, month is one-based, _not_ zero-based.
 * Returns:
 *   0 on success
 *  -1 on out of range
```

I'm not going to more-entertain this here, but maybe next go around.

## Playing around

We try first [`DEADBEEF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadbeef)in it which an isolation to track the marker 8 byte marker.

```
psql -d test -c 'COPY ( SELECT E'\''DEADBEEF'\'' ) TO STDOUT WITH ( FORMAT BINARY );' |
  od --skip-bytes=25 --endian big --read-bytes=8 -c
```

Now we swap that out..

```
psql -d test -c 'COPY ( SELECT $$2010-01-01 14:30$$::timestamp without time zone ) TO STDOUT WITH ( FORMAT BINARY );' |
  od --skip-bytes=25 --endian big --read-bytes=8 --format=d8 -x
```

Result: paren-comments added.

```
0000031      315671400000000  (timestamp in int8)
         0001 1f19 f9a9 aa00  (hex representation)
0000041
```

And that's your number for the first time zone. For `tsrange` as per the above section we have

- one byte for on the interval
- upper: 4 bytes (header) + 8 bytes (timestamp)
- lower: 4 bytes (header) + 8 bytes (timestamp)

So to access the first internal timestamp, we skip an addition 5 bytes, on top of already 25 bytes of skipage for 30 bytes total.

```
psql -d test -c 'COPY ( SELECT $$[2010-01-01 14:30, 2010-01-01 15:30)$$::tsrange ) TO STDOUT WITH ( FORMAT BINARY );' |
  od --skip-bytes=30 --endian big --read-bytes=8 --format=d8 -x
```

This gives us the same result as above..

```
0000036      315671400000000
         0001 1f19 f9a9 aa00
0000046
```

Simply change `--skip-bytes` to 42 to skip over that 8 byte time stamp, and the next 4 bytes of header for the `lower` and you'll get another time stamp.

Comment: timestamps can be integer or double. if it double it has flag in header for this?

Comment: @eri I don't think that information is in the dump, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4693.1237850133%40sss.pgh.pa.us however I don't know anyone not using int64 anymore.